# What is the interpretation of rsd in pyspark's approx_count_distinct and what are the consequences of changing it?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In the pyspark's [approx_count_distinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct.html) function there is a precision argument `rsd`. How does it work? What are the tradeoffs if it is increased or decreased? I guess for this one should understand how `approx_count_distinct` is implemented. Can you help me understand `rsd` in the context of the logic of `approx_count_distinct`?

Comment: [this](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2019/05/08/advanced-analytics-with-apache-spark.html) might be a helpful source on understanding how `approx_count_distinct` works. the tradeoff is basically how much accuracy you need versus the speed of the computation. `count_distinct` is exhaustive so you will almost certainly get the correct answer but it's computationally intensive – if you only need an approximation of the number of distinct values (to ~95% accuracy, for example) then `approx_count_distinct` is much faster

Comment: Problem is count_distinct does not work with windows. I wonder they have made it so. I achieve it with a combination of size and collect_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsd` is an abbreviation of "relative standard deviation", and its default value is 0.05. With this value, you control what the error is you're willing to accept on the distinct count. As @Derek O described in their comment above, the `approx_count_distinct` function makes a tradeoff between accuracy (which you control using the `rsd` parameter) and speed of the calculation.

To understand the underlying algorithm a bit more, we can have a quick look at the implementation of the [`approx_count_distinct`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L286-L296) function. We see that it uses the HyperLogLogPlusPlus algorithm (an improvement over the [HyperLogLog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) algorithm).

```scala
  /**
   * Aggregate function: returns the approximate number of distinct items in a group.
   *
   * @param rsd maximum relative standard deviation allowed (default = 0.05)
   *
   * @group agg_funcs
   * @since 2.1.0
   */
  def approx_count_distinct(e: Column, rsd: Double): Column = withAggregateFunction {
    HyperLogLogPlusPlus(e.expr, rsd, 0, 0)
  }
```

Apache Spark's [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/HyperLogLogPlusPlus.scala#L28-L42) of this `HyperLogLogPlusPlus` algorithm is based on the following papers (in Spark v3.3.1, time of writing this post):

- [HyperLogLog: the analysis of a near-optimal cardinality estimation algorithm](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlFuGaMe07.pdf) (this link is broken but I'm adding it for completeness sake)
- [HyperLogLog in Practice: Algorithmic Engineering of a State of The Art Cardinality Estimation Algorithm](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/pubs/archive/40671.pdf)
- [Appendix to HyperLogLog in Practice: Algorithmic Engineering of a State of the Art Cardinality Estimation Algorithm](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gyjfMHy43U9OWBXxfaeG-3MjGzejW1dlpyMwEYAAWEI/view?fullscreen#)

Comment: Took me some time to go through all the resources you have listed but once done I feel much better. Thank you yet again, dear friend :)

Comment: It's my pleasure as always :)