# How do I convert columns in a pyspark dataframe into hyperlog sketches for faster hyperloglog approximate count?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have several large dataframes (variable from hundreds to millions of rows) that look like this:

DataFrame A:

```
| user_id  |  
| -------- | 
|    1     | 
|    3     |
```

DataFrame B:

```
| user_id  |  
| -------- | 
|    6     | 
|    3     |
```

I want to combine these several dataframes in various different ways and measure the overlap. I have been running into the [Count Distinct problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count-distinct_problem#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20the%20count,known%20problem%20with%20numerous%20applications.), whereby these calculations are very costly and slow.

Spark SQL has a native function, approx_count_distinct that uses hyper logs to estimate the cardinality of data within ~5% accuracy. The problem, as I understand it, is that to truly speed up these calculations, the data itself needs to be converted to a hyperloglog sketch, whereby hashing speeds up this process.

I have found ways of converting data to sketches with Scala packages (like [spark-alchemy](https://github.com/swoop-inc/spark-alchemy)), but how could I do this with Spark SQL or pyspark, as opposed to scala?

I have tried using Scala in a separate part of my notebook, but for silly admin reasons, this isn't possible at the moment. I am forced to use Python/Pyspark/Spark SQL solutions at the moment. I have  done the calculations using count distinct (~8 hours) and approx count distinct (~4 hours), but if I can convert to sketches, I assume this will be a much quicker process.

Comment: `approxCountDistinct` dose use a variant of hyperloglog algortithm though? They call it hyperloglog++ or something like that

Comment: Yes they call it hyperloglog++, I wrote up an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75370109/15405732) a while back on this. Maybe this might be interesting to the OP.